# waiting for animation to stop

Tags: jquery, animation

I have to wait until the end of an animation to get correct offset().top value.

I've tried different methods (like promise) but none works: console.log is hit immediately. Why ? And what can I do ?

One of my tries :

```
$('#main').on('click', 'section > span', function() {

    el = $(this);

    var effect = function() {
      return $('.content').removeClass('showing').addClass('hiding').slideUp(300).attr("aria-hidden","true").closest('section').css('min-height','0');
    }

    $.when( effect() ).done(function() {
      var showTop = el.offset().top - 110;
      console.log(showTop);
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:showTop}, 'fast', function() {
        content.removeClass('hiding').addClass('showing').removeAttr("aria-hidden").slideDown(600);
      });
    });

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: which animation do you want to wait?

Comment: The one in the var effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `$.when` should be a promise/Deferred. You can use [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/#example-1) to get a promise for the element with the effect.

```
var effect = function() {
    $('.content').removeClass('showing').addClass('hiding').slideUp(300).attr("aria-hidden","true").closest('section').css('min-height','0');
    return $('.content').promise();
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot ! I have trouble understanding deferred/promise...